# Why does adding a Swift protocol in some situations not require all the normally required methods?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

For example, these are valid and will compile without (all) protocol stubs

```
public class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

}


class BLEController: CBCentralManager, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    }
}
```

Edit:  Solved!  Creating a class without inheriting from UIViewController or CBCentralManager still does comply with the delegate protocols, but it does not comply with NSObjectProtocol.  It just seems to be that I'm attempting to use the frameworks in an unintended way.

Comment: They could be optional requirements.

Comment: I was wondering if they would be.  I just tried creating a class to only the protocols (I left out UIViewController class and CBCentralManager class), and they still asked for all functions, so if they were truly optional it would still compile, right?

Comment: @Abrakebabra Can you show the code you tried?

Comment: They _are_ optional requirements (as @Frankenstein says), for both of those protocols.  If you Jump To Definition on those protocol types, you will see that they are.  (`CBCentralManagerDelegate` only has one non-optional func, which you implemented.)

Comment: If the protocol requirement are really optional the compiler would compile the code successfully.

Comment: I've done some inspecting from @Frankenstein's answer and it seems that the stubs that are required are for compliance with NSObject!  So when I try to create a class that tries to conform to say CBCentralManagerDelegate or SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate, my class doesn't conform to NSObject.

So if I were to try:
class BLEController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
}

The stubs that are asked for are not any of the delegate's protocol methods, but for NSObject only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why does my code compile without fulfilling all the protocol requirements?

What you are seeing here are [optional protocol requirements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID284). They are here because Swift code needs to interact with Objective-C, and Objective-C has them.

All methods except `centralManagerDidUpdateState` declared in `CBCentralManagerDelegate` are optional, [from here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate):

> The only required method is `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_:)`; the central manager calls this when its state updates, thereby indicating the availability of the central manager.

And `SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate`, only contains one optional method, [from here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizerdelegate):

> Use this protocol's optional method to track those changes and provide an appropriate response.

---

#### why does the code not compile if you remove the superclasses then?

This is because both of those protocols in your question also inherit from `NSObjectProtocol`, so they actually also have the additional requirements of `NSObjectProtocol`. `UIViewController` and `CBCentralManager` both inherits from `NSObject`, so they satisfy the `NSObjectProtocol` requirements, but your Swift class without a superclass doesn't.

Protocols with optional requirements don't have to inherit from `NSObjectProtocol` though. It's just that most of them are that way in the framework. You can for example do:

```
@objc protocol Foo {
    @objc optional func foo()
}

class FooClass : Foo {
    // compiles fine!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It compiles without needing the protocol stubs because all the requirement is optional. Check within the declaration of `SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate` it has only one requirement for a method called `availabilityDidChange` and you can see that it's `optional` from the keyword given at the beginning of the function.

In the second case, the `class` you have created doesn't inherit from `NSObject` but the first one does because it's a sub-class of `UIViewController` which in-turn is a sub-class of `NSObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It's because my classes without inheriting from UIViewController or CBCentralManager are not inheriting NSObject protocols which is why it's asking me for those functions.

Comment: Yes, some protocols specify that they should be assigned only to classes using `class` or `AnyObject` keyword. Sometimes the base-class you're inheriting already conforms to the protocol requirement hence the sub-class doesn't have to.